# Underscores in URLs are not correctly handled in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

I first wrote the following comment.

```
It is not true that there is just a _White House_: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow) that is called _White House_.
```

It was not rendered correctly, as it appeared as follows. (See the first comment for this question.)

> It is not true that there is just a *White House*: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow) that is called _White House.

To make it render correctly, I had to rewrite it as:

```
It is not true that there is just a _White House_: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,\_Moscow) that is called _White House_.
```

In this case, it is rendered correctly also in comments.

> It is not true that there is just a *White House*: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow) that is called *White House*.

Looking at the HTML produced for the comments, I understand what happened. In the first comment, the HTML is the following.

```
<span class="comment-copy">It is not true that there is just a <i>White House</i>: In Moscow, there is a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,%3Ci%3EMoscow" rel="nofollow">government building</a> that is called _White House.</span>
```

In the second comment, the HTML is the following.

```
<span class="comment-copy">It is not true that there is just a <i>White House</i>: In Moscow, there is a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow" rel="nofollow">government building</a> that is called <i>White House</i>.</span>
```

In the first comment, the URL is `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,%3Ci%3EMoscow` which means the underscore is changed to `<i>`, and then the brackets are encoded, giving as result the `%3Ci%3E` part that is visible in the URL.

This happens only in comments. If I write the following Markdown in a post, it is rendered correctly, as visible here.

```
It is not true that there is just a _White House_: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow) that is called _White House_.
```

> It is not true that there is just a *White House*: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow) that is called *White House*.

The HTML in this case is the following one.

```
<p>It is not true that there is just a <em>White House</em>: In Moscow, there is a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow" rel="nofollow">government building</a> that is called <em>White House</em>.</p>
```

Comment: It is not true that there is just a _White House_: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,_Moscow) that is called _White House_.

Comment: It is not true that there is just a _White House_: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House,\_Moscow) that is called _White House_.

Comment: Work-around would be to use single-asterisk notation. Parsing most likely breaks at the comma, because who expects a comma in an URL?! But I'm surprised that the parentheses in `[name](link)` do not seem to be the binding force.

Comment: Does it work as intended if the `,` is encoded?

Comment: It is not true that there is just a _White House_: In Moscow, there is a [government building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House%2C_Moscow) that is called _White House_.  <-- Comma encoded.